# Angular 4 form validation and Error Message

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular-forms, angular4-forms

I have to implement validation for forms in my application. I am using angular 4. I have 10 more forms in my application. I don't know if my question is valid or not. I am really confused with this implementation.

My question:
I need to add validation in form fields including mandatory and validation like email, phone number etc, If the user enter the form user knows some fields user may don't know what need to fill in other fields. But need to save valid fields and need to show the error message in form.

How can i implement in front end i am using Angular 4 and back end with nodejs

Comment: As written, this question is pretty broad. Adding an example of one form you're working through could help. Angular has a doc with examples on form validation: https://angular.io/guide/form-validation. Hope this helps to get you started.

Comment: @stealththeninja this not only validation. I need to validate fields and same time i need to save the valid field only to db . One thing i can do is need to check each field is valid or not before saving i don't think that's good idea. Any other suggestion?

Comment: I suggest creating a minimal, complete, verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Short of that, we're guessing what you're trying to build and repeating or linking to Angular docs.

Answer (score 6):

I suggest using the ReactiveFormsModule whenever working with forms. If you're not familiar with it, then check the documentation but it shouldn't be much of a problem since it's very simple.

```
form: FormGroup;

constructor(formBuilder: FormBuilder){
    this.form = formBuilder.group({
        name: ['', Validators.required],
        lastName: '',
        email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]]
     });
 }
```

So basically what's happening here is that we need a `FormGroup` instance when working with Reactive Forms. We use the `FormBuilder` class and call its `group` method, which takes an object of the form we want to create and returns the `FormGroup` instance. Each property of the object we pass will then be known as the FormGroup's FormControls, so in this example, we're declaring a FormGroup with three FormControls known as name, lastName and email.

The value of these FormControls is used for initialization and it can be either the actual value for that FormControl or an array where the first element will be the value of that FormControl and the second will be either a `ValidatorFn` or an array of `ValidatorFn`.

As you can see, we defined the name FormControl like this: `name: ['', Validators.required]` which means that the initial value will be an empty string and this FormControl will be required. The lastName is simply an empty string because we didn't want any validation for that field. The email is more interesting because this FormControl needs more than one validator, so we pass it an array.

And now, implementing all of this in our template is pretty easy as well

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <div>
        <input formControlName="email">
        <div *ngIf="form.get('email').hasError('required') && form.get('email').touched">This field is required</div>
        <div *ngIf="form.get('email').hasError('email') && form.get('email').touched">Invalid email format.</div>
    </div>
    ...
```

And if you don't want to allow the user to be able to submit the form until it's valid: `<button [disabled]="form.invalid">Save</button`